# I am trying to create Apple Development platform at AWS SNS with old p12 file. But unable to create

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to create Apple Development  platform at AWS SNS with old p12 file. But unable to create. This old p12 file is already used at another AWS SNS.

I am getting error i.e **Error loading Apple credentials from file**
Please help me

Comment: I am facing same error, please anyone help us

Comment: Did you find the solution ? @Zisu